# Hide a div when a custom field is empty

Tags: php, functions, custom-field, post-meta

I am having trouble hiding a div when the input of a custom field is empty. This is the code I am using but can not seem to get it to work. The field that displays the content is _cmb_fe_wysiwyg

```
 <?php
        if( empty( $post->post_content) ) {
           //empty
           }
        else {
              echo '<div id="ingredientsNeeded">';
                    echo '<h3>Ingredients</h3>';
                  echo wpautop( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $prefix . '_cmb_fe_wysiwyg', true ) ); 
                  echo '</div>';
           } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like:

```
 <?php $post = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_fe_wysiwyg', true) ; if (!empty($post)) { ?>
        <div id="ingredientsNeeded">
              <h3>Ingredients</h3>
              <?php echo wpautop( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $post . '_cmb_fe_wysiwyg', true ) );?>
        </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

This will check that the value is empty and if so will hide the div

Comment: perfect that worked like a charm